# Does the `overload` keyword make any difference?

Tags: delphi, overloading

Sometimes I have the "overload" keyword after a method that's not overloaded.

Besides readability and maintainability of the code, does this have any other impact that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The big difference is that when the arguments to a method are incorrect, the error message is significantly better for a non-overloaded method.

```
program Test;

procedure F(X: Integer);
begin
end;

procedure G(X: Integer); overload;
begin
end;

var
  P: Pointer = nil;

begin
  F(P); // E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Pointer'
  G(P); // E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'G' that can be called with these arguments
end.
```

More subtly, an overloaded method may be overloaded with functions you have no knowledge of. Consider the standard `IfThen` function. `StrUtils.IfThen` exists exactly once:

```
function IfThen(AValue: Boolean; const ATrue: string;
  AFalse: string = ''): string; overload; inline;
```

yet it is marked as `overload`. That's because it's overloaded with `Math.IfThen`, and if a single unit uses both `Math` and `StrUtils`, an unqualified `IfThen` will resolve to the proper function depending on the arguments, and regardless of the order of the units in the `uses` list.

Comment: Nice--I never knew it could be used to resolve such problems!